# Exporting 360 video in a 360 video format (not plain video)

Tags: 360video

I have the Insta360 One X camera and want to edit the video I take.

Basically I am putting the camera on a tripod and videoing 60 seconds. Then in Insta360 studio 2019 software I can edit the video to change the view angles (using keyframes) so when I play it looks like it is panning round.

When it is exported it always ends up as a plain video.

I want it to play as a 360 video so the user can pause it and also change the view angle if they want to look somewhere in particular then carry on playing the video again.

So far I can only find a way to export in a plain video & not in 360 video — can't this be done. Is there any other video editing software I can use (I don't mind paying a one off amount to buy it)?

Hope all that makes sense.

Comment: Note...I just used 'Spatial Media Metadata Injector.exe' to inject the metadata and the result was that it allows me to play the video and pause it & change the angle of view BUT it has changed the video to be a fish eye view and everything is close up and looks wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah Spatial Media Metadata Injector destroys the video. I was somehow able to export a video using insta360 studio as an actual 360 video but have no clue how I did it.

It seems all anyone wants to do is make claims to all these types of features but no one wants to explain how they're doing anything. The information people are leaving is useless.

I was on the phone with insta360 today for about 40 minutes trying to have them explain to me what a keyframe is, what purpose it serves and why it's even in insta360 studio to begin with.